# Bitwise operators on unsigned long?

Tags: c++, variables, operators, bit-manipulation, long-integer

I'm currently working with a hash function as such:

```
unsigned long hashFunc(const char *str, unsigned int tablesize ) // djb2 hash
{   
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;
    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash)+ c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return (hash & tablesize)-1;
}
```

Apparently, though, the bitwise operator & fails for some long values and returns the max value of long instead. For instance, hashing the word "care" with tablesize of 63 is returning 0xffffffff.

Are bitwise operators not intended to work for unsigned long ints? If so, what other options do I have?

Comment: Bitwise operators work fine on `unsigned long`.  Step through your code in a debugger (or just add print statements) in order to isolate the problem.

Comment: Ahh, I realized I didn't check for value of 0 before subtracting one, which I suppose is pretty crucial. But that is still strange. When you subtract one from an unsigned variable does it go to 0xffffffff by default?

Comment: Yes.  For unsigned types, the number range just wraps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put "-1" within the parenthesis:

```
return (hash & (tablesize - 1));
```

This only works if tablesize is known to be a power of two.

If tablesize is not a power of two, then you should use the modulo operator "%":

```
return hash % tablesize;
```

(No "-1" is required in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The two types - `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` might have different sizes, which might cause the bitwise operation to do something you did not expect.
Try casting:

```
return (hash & (unsigned long)tablesize)-1;
```

(Or use `static_cast`, if you insist)

Comment: The cast happens implicitly, so this should make no difference.

Comment: You should always use static_cast (or appropriate). The thought of using a C-style cast should never cross a C++ programmer's mind. The fact that they are equivalent is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it a little bit, and it seems to work just fine.
Simply, as a bad luck - the value of `hash` for `("care",63)` is `0x17c9504c0` and when you perform a binary-and with `0x3f` you get plain 0. Subtract 1 and you get `0xffffffffffffffff`.

The problem is in your code, not in the machine :)